# Angular bind HTML inside controller?

Tags: angularjs

I currently have a data feed in my Angular setup which returns certain data as HTML.  For example, it returns:

```
"It&#8217;s".
```

In the template, I can use `ng-bind-html` so that it displays as "It's", but how do I do this within the controller?  I need to do this as I am setting the page title dynamically, but it is displaying the HTML characters above, rather than formatting it correctly.

E.g. using:

```
$scope.name = data.word (but formats HTML?)
```

Comment: This should get you started https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

Answer (score 0):

inject $sce and use the following code

$scope.name = $sce.trustAsHtml(data.word;

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I've added this to the controller, but it is still displaying the HTML codes in the page title.  Am i missing something?

Comment: Have you inject Sanitize in your controller ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this.  I simply placed the `ng-bind-html` onto the `<title>` tag. So:

```
<title ng-bind-html="seo.pageTitle"></title>
```